# Multiple conditions in a Case statement for one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Customers like so:

```
Name    City    Country    Product
John    London  UK         Crisps
Paul    Perth   Australia  Juice
George  Manaus  Brazil     Bread
Ringo   Tokyo   Japan      Chocolate
```

I need to do a Select statement based on if 2 column values match in another table such as this:

```
Country    Product
UK         Crisps
Australia  Crips
Brazil     Chocolate
Japan      Chocolate
```

Both values need to exist in the table, as in i need to select a row in table A where BOTH values exists in a row in table B, in Table A there a row where Country is UK and product is Crisps, that should be returned but Country being Australia and Product being crisps should not be returned.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have tried to join the tables but had no luck, i also tried EXISTS in a select statement but that also would not let me do it, i am now out of ideas

Comment: Crips or Crisps, typo?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: please add expected output for your data

Comment: So you are showing two different tables in your request and you want to select all pairs of country and product that exist in both tables? Sounds like a simple `INTERSECT` operation to me as shown in Mayank's answer. Or is it something else that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better sql would be

SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE 0 < (SELECT count(1) FROM table2 t2 where t2.country = t1.country and t2.product = t1.product);

Comment: No. What gives you the idea that this would be a "better" query? Why must we count all occurences when we only want to know whether at least one exists? Why `COUNT(1)`? This counts records for which a 1 is not null, which is only an obfuscated way of merely counting rows with `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: [Correlated subquereis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) can lead to a performance hit.  This problem can be solved without running that risk.

Comment: Usually the country or product kind of columns are index based columns, so  it will be faster if you check only those records  matching with table t1 columns. And select count(1) is faster than count(*).

Comment: That's nonsense. It's of course not faster to to read all records for a country and product and count them instead of merely looking for the existence of one such record. Neither can `COUNT(1)` be faster than `COUNT(*)`. The latter counts rows, nothing more. The former (if taken literally and not optimized to `COUNT(*)` internally by the DBMS's optimizer) generates a 1 for each record, then checks whether that 1 is not null, and then counts that record. How can this possibly be faster than a mere `COUNT(*)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select Name, Product from Table_1
intersect
select Name, Product from Table_2
```

Comment: Why the downvote? As far as I understand the question, this seems to be the straight-forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a basic `join`:

```
select c.*
from customers c join
     table2
     on t2.country = c.country and t2.product = t.product;
```

Or you could use `exists`.